# Class Library .NET Standard and mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, .net, class-library, .net-standard

I created new project: Class Library .NET Standard 1.4 where I want to use 'Thread' class.
I need to add _Thread reference to a mscorlib.dll. Later I can't compile project, because I have error message:

> 'Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported'.

Why? What can I do right now?

Comment: You don't like .NETStandard.  Don't use it.  Or use Task.

Comment: I changed to .NET Framework. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to add _Thread reference to a mscorlib.dll.

No, you are not supposed to add reference to a platform specific libraries such as mscorlib.dll. Your class library targeting .NET Standard can only reference other libraries targeting the same or lower versions of .NET Standard.

Regarding the Thread class, it will be added to .NET Standard v2.0.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `Thread` in .NET Standard < 2.0, install the NuGet package `System.Threading.Thread` via the NuGet package manager or via console:

```
dotnet add package System.Threading.Thread
```

It will be available automatically in .NET Standard 2.0.